# What is the difference between -startTime and startTime?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning a StopWatch Project with Swift.The ultimate app is like this:

[image]

However, there is a problem when defining the class stopWatch.

Why is there an "-" before "startTime"?What is the difference between "- startTime" and "startTime"?

I haven't found this in the NSDate Class Reference Documentation.Also, when I delete the "-", there is no difference for the ultimate app.

Code is here:

class Stopwatch {

```
private var startTime: NSDate?

var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval {
    if let startTime = self.startTime {
        return -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between ten seconds and minus ten seconds?

Comment: It's just an ordinary negative sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `timeIntervalSinceNow` is exactly that: the time interval (seconds) since now up until that date (in this case, `startTime`). Assuming that `startTime` is a date in -say- 15 seconds in the future, that should give you +15 seconds.

But your app is a stop watch: `startTime` is a date *in the past* (i.e., the moment when you started the chronometer) so `timeIntervalSinceNow` will likely give you a negative number of seconds, because you are counting "back in time" (i.e., starting *now* and counting up until some date *in the past*). That is why you need the minus sign: so that you get the (positive) number of seconds from start time until now.

Comment: Thank you. "startTime" is a relative term.